# Enable colors in Ubuntu Server linux terminal

Tags: terminal, colors, ubuntu-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TTY with 256 colors?](https://superuser.com/questions/67582/tty-with-256-colors)

One of my dev machines is an Ubuntu server installation with no X/gui/etc. It just boots to terminal. Can I enable 256 colors here? How?

Comment: Look at this question: http://superuser.com/questions/67582/tty-with-256-colors

Comment: this does appear to be asking how to configure 256-color Virtual Terminals; closing as duplicate.  i expect you can get 256 colors on a typical pseudo-TTY, eg, by SSH'ing into the box from your favorite terminal emulator (PuTTY, gnome-terminal, etc) running on another box, or even by running gnome-terminal on the dev box and displaying back to a remote X-server.  if you'd like to explore the other options, please edit your question and flag for moderator attention to request it be reopened.

Answer (score -2):

Check out some answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263892/change-the-background-color-in-gnome-terminal-through-a-command).

Comment: *gnome-terminal* is a terminal emulator program that runs in X and connects to a pseudo-TTY.  not the same thing as a hardware TTY.