# Console disable Vim color scheme (ctrl+alt+F1...)

Tags: vim, ubuntu, console, terminal, gnome-shell

I don't know exactly how is named all the `ctrl+alt+F1`, `ctrl+alt+F2`, `ctrl+alt+F3` etc... terminals but when I'm going to use it all my Vim scheme is ignored...

I made it following this website:
http://codissimo.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/enhancing-vim-as-an-htmljscssphp-editor/

Heres all `~/.vimrc`

```
if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
    set term=gnome-256color
    set t_Co=256
    colorscheme railscasts
else
    colorscheme default
endif


"FileType support
set filetype=on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

"Color scheme and font
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php colorscheme railscasts
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set gfn=Monaco\ 10

"Indentation
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set ai
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set sw=4
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set ts=4
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set sts=4
autocmd FileType javascript,css,php set textwidth=79

"Enable autocompletion
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS

"Enable line numbers
autocmd FileType javascript,css,php set number

"Enable incremental search
autocmd FileType javascript,html,css,php set incsearch
```

This part should have been fixed it right?

```
if $COLORTERM == 'gnome-terminal'
    set term=gnome-256color
    set t_Co=256
    colorscheme railscasts
else
    colorscheme default
endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those tty1..12s don’t support 256 colours, so pretending they do doesn’t help. Apparently you can make them support it, though, as seen in [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/67582/tty-with-256-colors).