# 256 color display in linux command-line?

Tags: linux, command-line, colors

Is it possible to have the linux command line (no graphical interface/X server) display 256 color like most terminals do? And if not, whats stopping it from being developed?

Comment: what Terminal Emulator application are you using? there are dozens of them. That will determine what your capabilities are, but without knowing more about your install theres not much more we can say. Every terminal emulator I've used with a modern linux distro handled at least 8bit color for backgrounds, text, and color-coded tokens (files green, folders blue, good links light blue, dead links red, etc).

Comment: Syne wants 256 colour support on the Linux console. They specifically said it wasn't about X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was discussed several times (usually in other forums), concluding that you can do this, but relying upon fbterm (framebuffers).

Further reading:

- [Can fbterm support 256 colors?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235455/can-fbterm-support-256-colors)
- [256 colors in console (tty)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254234/256-colors-in-console-tty/254249)
- [Can the Linux tty support 256 colors?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=101996) (Arch Linux)
- [TTY with 256 colors?](https://superuser.com/questions/67582/tty-with-256-colors)